# how to check if at least one variable has a specific value

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Is there a shorted way to write the following expression in python?

I am looking to check if at least one of the variables has the value "None"

thank you

```
if hBorder1!="None" or hBorder2!="None" or vBorder1!="None" or vBorder2 !="None":
        return "BorderByType"
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: The code you show returns `BorderByType` if even *one* of them is *not* `"None"`. Is that what you want? It returns `""` only if *all* of the have the value `"None"`.

Comment: Thats right. It would only take one to have a value != "None" to return a "BorderByType". returning "" only if all of them are set to "None"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if any(b!="None" for b in (hBorder1, hBorder2, vBorder1, vBorder2)):
        return "BorderByType"
    else:
        return ""
```

Or...

```
return ('', "BorderByType")[int(any(b!="None" for b in (hBorder1, hBorder2, vBorder1, vBorder2)))]
```

Comment: the cast to `int` is unnecessary. apart from that: nice!

Comment: woudl this also work?   `borders=[hBorder1,hBorder2,vBorder1,vBorder2]
 if any(b!="None" for b in borders):
  return "BorderByType"
 else:
  return ""`

Answer (score 2):

```
if "None" in (hBorder1, hBorder2, vBorder1, vBorder2):
    ...
```

This will short-circuit at the first "None" value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "None" not in [hBorder1, hBorder2, vBorder1, vBorder2]
    return "BorderByType"
else:
    return "
```

or

```
return "BorderByType" if "None" not in [hBorder1, hBorder2, vBorder1, vBorder2] else ''
```

Comment: Not quite. Only one of the variables needs a non-"None" value to return `"BorderByType"`; this requires *all* of them.